# Access a JSTL variable from JSP expression tag

Tags: jsp

I need to add up the price of the products to display **Grand Total** for every order. I am traversing through a list of orders `${order.purchaseItems}` and I need to access the price of the Purchased Items and add it up in the JSP itself but I can't figure out how to access it in the JSP Expression tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
                        
        <%! int grandTotal=0;%>
                        
        <c:forEach items="${order.purchaseItems}" var="item">
                            
            <tr>
                <td>${item.productJ.manufacturer}</td>
                <td>${item.productJ.item}</td>
                <td>${item.productJ.description}</td>
                <td>${item.quantity}</td>
                <td>${item.price}</td>
                <%= grandTotal += ${item.price}; %>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Grand Total: </td>
                <td><%= grandTotal %></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it did! Thanks again @Swati